# How can I create reminders based on (list-holidays)?

Tags: calendar

I'd like to create reminders in advance of holidays, `(list-holidays)`, 30 and 90 days in advance. Is there any utility that could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this method to insert three TODOs per holiday:

1. The day itself
2. 30 days before the holiday
3. 90 days before the holiday

An example of the output:

```
* TODO New Year's Day
SCHEDULED: <2025-01-01 Wed>
* TODO New Year's Day in 30 days
SCHEDULED: <2024-12-02 Mon>
* TODO New Year's Day in 90 days
SCHEDULED: <2024-10-03 Thu>
```

```
(defun cashpw/org--insert-holiday-reminders (year)
  "Insert TODO reminders for holidays."
  (interactive
   (let* ((year (calendar-read-sexp
                 "Year?"
                 (lambda (x) (> x 0))
                 (calendar-extract-year (calendar-current-date)))))
     (list
      year)))
  (let ((all-holidays
         (s-split
          "\n"
          (progn
            (list-holidays
             year
             year
             (append
              holiday-general-holidays
              holiday-christian-holidays))
            (with-current-buffer holiday-buffer
              (buffer-string))))))
    (cl-labels ((insert-reminder
                  (name schedule-time)
                  (progn
                    (org-insert-heading)
                    (org-todo
                     "TODO")
                    (insert
                     name)
                    (org-schedule
                     nil
                     (format-time-string
                      "%F %a"
                      schedule-time)))))
      (--map
       (cl-destructuring-bind
           (date-string
            holiday-name)
           ;; Example Monday, January 1, 2024: New Year's Day
           (s-split
            ": "
            it)
         (let ((holiday-time (date-to-time
                              date-string)))
           (insert-reminder
            holiday-name
            holiday-time)
           (insert-reminder
            (s-concat
             holiday-name
             " in 30 days")
            (time-subtract
             holiday-time
             (days-to-time 30)))
           (insert-reminder
            (s-concat
             holiday-name
             " in 90 days")
            (time-subtract
             holiday-time
             (days-to-time 90)))))
       all-holidays)))
  (kill-buffer holiday-buffer))
```

Comment: Is this an answer to the question, or is this answer should really be included in the question.  I am confused ....